# How to partition data, then remove groups if there are duplicates?

Tags: r

I currently have a data frame that looks a bit like this:

```
   ID val
1   1   a
2   1   b
3   2   a
4   2   b
5   2   b
6   3   c
7   3   a
8   4   a
9   5   a
10  5   b
```

What I am wanting is to remove a whole group of IDs if there are duplicate values. So the output that I am wanting is this:

```
  ID val
1  1   a
2  1   b
3  3   c
4  3   a
5  4   a
6  5   a
7  5   b
```

I have come across solutions to remove individual rows, but not chunks of data. Would I be using a loop for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can `group_by` `ID` and select groups if there are no duplicates in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!any(duplicated(val)))

#     ID val  
#  <int> <fct>
#1     1 a    
#2     1 b    
#3     3 c    
#4     3 a    
#5     4 a    
#6     5 a    
#7     5 b
```

---

Or using base R `ave`

```
df[!with(df, as.logical(ave(val, ID, FUN = function(x) any(duplicated(x))))), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R,

```
df[!df$ID %in% unique(df$ID[duplicated(df)]),]

#   ID val
#1   1   a
#2   1   b
#6   3   c
#7   3   a
#8   4   a
#9   5   a
#10  5   b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `base R` method that use `table` with `rowSums` to identify the 'ID's to keep

```
df[df$ID %in% names(which(!rowSums(table(df) > 1))),]
#    ID val
#1   1   a
#2   1   b
#6   3   c
#7   3   a
#8   4   a
#9   5   a
#10  5   b
```